# ¿Como Descargar un archivo PDF automáticamente con PHP y tFPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

Tengo una duda con respecto a como hacer para descargar un archivo PDF automáticamente con PHP y tFPDF sin que se visualice en el navegador.

Tengo un formulario de registro de usuarios y lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de registrar a mi nuevo usuario en la base de datos me descargue un archivo PDF en automático con los algunos datos que se ingresaron en dicho formulario.
Estuve investigando en internet y en algunos ejemplo que vi utilizan la función `header()`, trate de adaptarlo a mi código pero no me funciona, será que me pueden apoyar guiándome para solucionar mi problema.

Así tengo el script donde tengo lo de el archivo PDF.

```
function obtenerPDF($usuario, $contrasena)
{    
include 'tfpdf/tfpdf.php';
    $archivo = new tFPDF();
    $archivo->AddPage();
    $archivo->AddFont('PT_Sans', '', 'PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf', true);
    $archivo->SetFont('PT_Sans', '', 10);
    $archivo->SetMargins(24, 0 , 0);
    $archivo->Cell(164, 20, "", 0, 1, "C");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 20, "REGISTRO Y SEGUIMIENTO DE USUARIOS", 0, 1, "C");
    $pagina = "www.misistema.com";
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "Para finalizar tu registro debes:", 0, 1, "L");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "1.- Acceder a la página: $pagina", 0, 1, "L");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "2.- Ingresar con tu usuario y contraseña: " , 0, 1, "L");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "Usuario: $usuario", 0, 1, "C");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "Contraseña: $contrasena", 0, 1, "C");
    $archivo->Cell(164, 7, "3.- Completar la información que se te pide y guardarla" , 0, 1, "L");
    $archivo->Output();
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='bienvenido.pdf'");
    readfile("$fullName.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos solo deberias cambiar esto:

```
$archivo->Output();
```

por esto:

```
$archivo->Output("test.pdf", "D");
```

con esto forzas la descarga de tu archivo pdf

Ejemplo de codigo:

```
  $pdf = new tFPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
    //Aquí escribimos lo que deseamos mostrar
    $total =0;
    //titulo de reporte
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(195,5,'Reporte de Gastos',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    $titulo ='Desde: '.$desde.' Hasta: '.$hasta;
    $pdf->Cell(195,5,$titulo,1,0,'C');
    //encabezado
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'Fecha',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,'Descripcion ',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,'Valor',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,'observaciones',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,'Responsable',1,0,'C');
    //agregando la data
    foreach($result as $item) {
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Cell(30,5,$item['fecha'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(50,5,$item['descripcion'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(25,5,$item['valor'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(50,5,$item['observaciones'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(40,5,$item['persona'],1,0,'C');
        $total+=$item['valor'];
    }  
    //total
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,'Total: ',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$total,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,'',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,'',1,0,'C');
    //FORZANDO DESCARGA
    $pdf->Output("test.pdf",'D');
```

**Resultado:**
[image: Resultado]
Espero te sirva...!!